# Python, open for writing if exists, otherwise raise error

Tags: python, file, error-handling

Is there an option I can pass open() that will cause an IOerror when trying to write a nonexistent file? I am using python to read and write block devices via symlinks, and if the link is missing I want to raise an error rather than create a regular file. I know I could add a check to see if the file exists and manually raise the error, but would prefer to use something built-in if it exists.

Current code looks like this:

```
device = open(device_path, 'wb', 0)
device.write(data)
device.close()
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any built-in method to do this in one step, no.

Comment: You can use `os.path.isfile()` to check though

Comment: What you could do is opening the file in `w+` mode and see if there's any data in the file already.

Comment: well checking the return of open is pretty much a 'builtin' solution...

Comment: The problem here is that a file is created, and the symlink can't be added back if udev is trying to do that in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
open(path, 'r+b')
```

Specifying the "r" option means the file must exist and you can read.
Specifying "+" means you can write and that you will be positioned at the end.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?#open

Comment: This in combination with seek(0) got me what I wanted!

Comment: Also, I ended up needing to be a symlink, so I now use the os.path.islink function before opening the file.

Comment: Nice! I thought you missed my answer. The responses just repeating what you said in your question was frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`os.path.islink()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.islink) or [`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check if the file exists.

Answer (score 2):

Doing the check each time is a nuisance, but you can always wrap `open()`:

```
import os

def open_if_exists(*args, **kwargs):
    if not os.path.exists(args[0]):
        raise IOError('{:s} does not exist.'.format(args[0]))
    f = open(*args, **kwargs)
    return f

f = open_if_exists(r'file_does_not_exist.txt', 'w+')
```

This is just quick and dirty, so it doesn't allow for usage as: `with open_if_exists(...)`.

## Update

The lack of a context manager was bothering me, so here goes:

```
import os
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def open_if_exists(*args, **kwargs):
    if not os.path.exists(args[0]):
        raise IOError('{:s} does not exist.'.format(args[0]))
    f = open(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        yield f
    finally:
        f.close()

with open_if_exists(r'file_does_not_exist.txt', 'w+') as f:
    print('foo', file=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid  you can't perform the check of file existence and raise error using the `open()` function.

Below is the signature of `open()` in python where `name` is the file_name, `mode` is the access mode and `buffering` to indicate if buffering is to be performed while accessing a file.

> open(name[, mode[, buffering]])

Instead, you can check if the file exists or not.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isfile(file_name)
```

This will return `True` or `False` depending on if the file exists. To test a file specifically, you can use this.

To test the existence of  both files and directories, you can use:

```
>>> os.path.exists(file_path)
```